# Fetch very huge data from server and insert in sqlite - Android

Tags: android

I am working on a project which having millions of records in server, i need to fetch these data from server via web services and insert into Sqlite database.

Problem is, in order to fetch these details from server its taking too much time because the data retriving from server is very huge.

Also its taking too much time to insert into Sqlite database.

Anyone can give me a possible workaround for this.

Comment: Used `AsyncTask` Thread to retrieve data from Server and used `SQLite Transaction` for inserting Huge data into `Sqlite`

Answer (score 1):

Used `AsyncTask class` for fetching data from Server

> The **AsyncTask class** encapsulates the creation of a background process
>   and the synchronization with the main thread. It also supports
>   reporting progress of the running tasks.

More Information go to: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

And database operations are slow and in a situation where thousands of records have to be inserted, inserting each record consumes a lot of time and affects the performance of the application. In such situations,batch insert saves some overhead. A significant amount of time can be saved if batch inserts are made in a single transaction.

`SQLite` provides three simple methods in `SQLiteDatabase` class :

1. beginTransaction();
2. setTransactionSuccessful();
3. endTransaction();

More information go to: http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/tag/android-example/

Answer (score 0):

fetch data from server in different thread like asyntask and insert that data in also seperate thread.. and create a broadcast receiver so that when data finish inserting , it will notify you that data is loaded into your app database.

Comment: thanks for your reply, the problem in this approach is in the launcher activity itself i need to fetch these data, in the first activity I am having an AutoCompleteTextView, that autocompletetextview has to give a suggestion from DB based on the text entered. If its going to be a Asyntask, it will run in backgroud and the user will not know that my app is fetching details from server in background and the suggestion list cannot be shown to user

Comment: you can show progressdialog while searching. so user will know that app is getting data from server.

Comment: i can show progrssdialog but its taking too much time

Comment: you limit your records upto some no. and show a button with text "more" , so when user click on it it will again fetch some no. of records from server.

Comment: to search what is entered in textbox is not a problem, i can search in server based on the text entered in textbox, how can i show the suggestion list for AutoCompleteTextview to the user when the app is fetching details from server

Comment: thats what i said , show user limited no. of results and give something like "more button" and when user click again fetch records and concatenate with the previous one's.

Comment: can you give me a link for that, loading suggestion list from server for an autocompletetextview

Comment: see here , this might help you. https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Asynctask you can use IntentService, which is more optimal than Asynctask. Moreover it runs on a seperate thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is a really very bad idea to have millions of records getting stored on a mobile device. If it is really needed a web application should suffice.

And if at all this requirement is needed, then you could specify pages, that is in one page, call for some records, keep a count of total items, and update the page numbers. Use a service also in order to make subsequent calls to the server for the data, and meanwhile try to display some items to the users whilst other items get added from the service.

Comment: i meant pages for the webservice call, that is you could have the url/page_number here..  :)